# Android Webview css error

Tags: android, css, android-webview

My android app loads into a webview a web application in a unique html.

My css is huge like 350kb. Sometimes in slow connections(mainly EDGE) not all the styles seems to load correct.

Some images (I am using data uris) are missing and some parts simply doesn't load the css styles.
I've tried to put the style inline in page (supposing that the css file got errors) but with no effect.

It seems like the android webview just stops the css parsing and shows the page.
Has anybody experienced something like this? How could I fix this in a nice way?

I have tested in Gingerbread only.

Comment: Can you share a link to the page in question?

Answer (score 0):

I think using of mobile app web-based is to be more lighter then the desktop equivalent, because of slower connection of this devices. Have you try to separate the css to see if this issue is because of big loading?